# Backup battery and capacitor

Tags: capacitor, raspberry-pi, supercapacitor

I want to have a capacitor to keep my RPI from "powerdown" when the supply goes from the 5v Samsung charger to the power bank. I have the redundancy diodes and the primary output is Samsung charger. When I switch from battery to mains the RPI does not shutdown. When from mains to battery it shut down.

Now I tried wiring 4x 330uf cap in series for total 990uf across the rpi vin/gnd (I do not know if I connect the charge resistor correct - in series with the load/rpi). The rpi did not boot.

I do have some 2200uf caps also.

Comment: 1) include a schematic 2) wiring capacitors in series is usually **pointless** and in your situation I am 100% sure that it is **pointless**.

Comment: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-13/series-and-parallel-capacitors/

Comment: 1. The capacitors you are using will only run the Pi for a fraction of a second. 2. Don't wire them in series, it reduces the capacitance. 3. What is this "charge resistor" and what's it for?

Comment: Omg. I cannot believe I just did that. Now parallel !

Comment: The link does not explain why the rpi do not boot when the <330uf capacitor is connected.(4x 330uf in series = <330uf total)

Comment: You should be using 5.5 volt capacitors of 0.5 Farads or more. The CPU has built-in UVLO so as soon as Vcc drops the CPU resets. A 1 farad capacitor *might* buy you an extra second of run time. There are many Pi hats out there with battery backup and reset/sleep mode. What is wrong with using them?